# Comparing salaries in different countries

Tags: descriptive-statistics, finance

I have a number of salary figures for roles that I want to compare across various countries. Obviously each country has their own currency and living costs.

A simple way of comparing would be to use the current exchange rate.

Is there a more reasonable figure of "buying power" or something similar that I could use instead? Something that may incorporate living costs, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use purchasing power parity to compare the value of currency in different countries.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing_power_parity

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was after.